# Ruby on Rails: making id in column as an alias?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there a way to change the name of the `id` column in model?

If I have something like this:

```
pg_search_scope :good_search, :against => [:first_name, :last_name, :id]
```

I'd like to change the `:id, as: :somethingelse` so when I check my json values, instead of `id`, I'll have `somethingelse` to reference in a loop:

```
<% @example.each do |e| %>
  <%= e.somethingelse %> #instead of e.id
<% end %>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try `alias_attribute`

```
class ModelClass < Activerecord::Base
  alias_attribute :somethingelse, :id
end
```

[rails documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/alias_attribute)

Comment: I tried doing this, and changing my `pg_search_scope` with `:somethingelse` in it, instead of `:id`, but then I get an error: `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column model.somethingelse does not exist`

Comment: rails documentation clearly shows it should work. What is the SQL query generated? Does it work when used outside the named scope, like `Model.first.somethingelse`?

Comment: it does work, why is that when I tried to put `:somethingelse` into `pg_search_scope :good_search, :against => [:first_name, :last_name, :somethingelse]`, there's an issue. Is there another method to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Well if i understand correctly you wanna `somethingelse` to return and `id`?

Why not to use something like that in your @example.class model:

```
def somethingelse
  id
end
```

Or if you already have database with column which is named differently

```
set_primary_key :somethingelse #in you model
```